# WPF Button Style Trigger fired twice

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm currently working on a .NET 4.7.1 WPF application. I have an attached behavior on a button style on the IsPressed handler. I can reach the event handler.

However, when I click the button, the event gets somehow *fired twice* unfortunately.

My xaml looks like this:

```
<WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
    <Button Style="{StaticResource MySaveButton}">
        Save
    </Button>
</WrapPanel>
```

My style looks like this:

```
<Style TargetType="Button" BasedOn="{StaticResource SomeOtherBaseStyle}" x:Key="MySaveButton">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="localBehaviors:MyBehavior.Save" Value="True" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

My behavior class looks like this:

```
 public class MyBehavior : Behavior<UIElement>
 {
     public static readonly DependencyProperty SaveProperty =
         DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Save", typeof(bool), typeof(MyBehavior), new UIPropertyMetadata(OnSave));

     public static bool GetSave(DependencyObject obj) => (bool)obj.GetValue(SaveProperty);

     public static void SetSave(DependencyObject obj, bool value) => obj.SetValue(SaveProperty, value);

     private static void OnSave(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
     {
        // gets triggered twice when I click the button. Should be raised only once.
        // ... some logic
     }
}
```

Do you know how to fire the event only one time, using the style trigger?

Thank you very much!

Comment: I guess it will be called when pressing and when releasing the button. To find out, which of the 2 cases you have, you could check the value of `e.NewValue` in the `OnSave` method (will be only true, when pressing and not when releasing the button)

Comment: yes, indeed - thank you very much!

Comment: I will post it as answer so that you can close the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trigger is executing when the value of `IsPressed` changes (from `true` to `false` or the other way round). 
That means it is called when pressing and when releasing the button.

To check, which direction caused the trigger, you can check `e.NewValue`:

```
private static void OnSave(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.NewValue)
    {
        // changed from unpressed to pressed
    }
}
```